# thisArg in Array Methods

Tags: javascript, filter, this

```
let army = {
  minAge: 18,
  maxAge: 27,
  canJoin(user) {
    return user.age >= this.minAge && user.age < this.maxAge;
  }
};

let users = [
  {age: 16},
  {age: 20},
  {age: 23},
  {age: 30}
];

let soldiers = users.filter(army.canJoin, army);

alert(soldiers.length); // 2
alert(soldiers[0].age); // 20
alert(soldiers[1].age); // 23
```

The above code works fine.
But this:

```
let soldiers = users.filter(army.canJoin);
```

...doesn't work as intended.

My understanding,

Here we care calling `army.canJoin` function with `{age:16}` as a an argument.

When the execution reaches `canJoin(user)`, 
it checks for `this.minAge` , Now as I have learned the value of **this is the method called before the dot**
ie. `army.Canjoin` ( Canjoin was called with army ) Hence it should take army as this.

But it's seems like it doesn't take army as this

Why?

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` binds the context with the element of the array by default. You can change this behavior by the following ways

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
let army = {
  minAge: 18,
  maxAge: 27,
  canJoin(user) {
    return user.age >= this.minAge && user.age < this.maxAge;
  }
};

let users = [
  {age: 16},
  {age: 20},
  {age: 23},
  {age: 30}
];

let soldiers1 = users.filter(army.canJoin, army);
let soldiers2 = users.filter(army.canJoin.bind(army));
let soldiers3 = users.filter(user => army.canJoin(user));

console.log(soldiers1); 
console.log(soldiers2);
console.log(soldiers3);
```

Comment: Can you please elobrate buddy, what binding the context mean. I am new to Js, just started learning

Comment: It is like a value of `this` variable _(not exactly)_ binds at the runtime. For more check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Array#filter` without `thisArg` would look like this:

```
function filter(cb){
  const output = []
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if(cb(this[i], i, this))
      output.push(this[i])
  return output
}
```

Here, the `army.canJoin` becomes `cb`, and where the function is called, there's no context: `cb(`*`/* ... */`*`)`.

This is where `thisArg` comes in. `Array#filter` was designed to apply a `this` value passed to it:

```
function filter(cb, thisArg){
  const output = []
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if(cb.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this))
      output.push(this[i])
  return output
}
```

In this case, the `cb` is `call`-ed, that allows setting a custom `this` value, `Array#filter` applies `thisArg`, and it starts to work.

> **Note!** `Array#filter` is a native method, so in reality, its code isn't defined in JS-land

Answer (score 0):

TLTR: Even though you call `army.canJoin()` with the dot, this is not a method call, because `canJoin` was defined as a normal function (inside an object) and not a method (as defined as part of a class). So when called it is treated as a plain function, without any binding to `army` whatsoever, despite the dot notation. Within `canJoin`, `this` refers to the global object by default, and nothing else.

In order to tell the function call what `this` you want it to see, you use the standard `bind` method:

```
const canJoinUser = army.canJoin.bind(army);
canJoinUser(user)   // should give expected result for this user
```

When you pass `thisArg` to `filter` like this:

```
 let soldiers = users.filter(army.canJoin, army);
```

You are actually asking `filter` to do that same `bind` job for you on every call of `canJoin`.

Comment: I fail to understand the "...and not a method..." part of your answer. It just might be that you're mistaken about something - I invite you to read + comment on the "update" section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You buy a spoon, and your neighbour buys the same spoon. Your 5 year-old takes your spoon out of your drawer, leaves the house, and asks an extraterrestrial 'is that daddy's spoon?' - the extraterrestrial shrugs. Next scene, the extraterrestrial is at your house, your 5 year-old opens the drawer, and asks again; 'yes' says the extraterrestrial.

The spoon doesn't have your initials on it. It doesn't know it's *your* spoon. It can't and it mustn't. Well, not until you *did* put your initials on it, and after that, it isn't 'the same spoon your neighbour bought' any longer.

Your function `canJoin` is that spoon, your neighbour runs a kindergarten, and the extraterrestrial is the JS runtime.

```
let kindergarten = {
    minAge: 2,
    maxAge: 6
};

function canJoin(user) {
    return user.age >= this.minAge && user.age < this.maxAge;
}

army.canJoin = canJoin; kindergarten.canJoin = canJoin;
```

You say in your question 'canJoin was called with army' - that is the error.

If you do `army.canJoin({user: 9999})`, then `canJoin` was called with army - the spoon is in your drawer. If you do `kindergarten.canJoin({user: 9999})`, then `canJoin` was called with kindergarten - the spoon is in your neighbour's drawer. And if you call some function, like `Array.filter`, and pass as an argument either `army.canJoin` or `kindergarten.canJoin` or simply `canJoin`, then the spoon is out of the drawer. It couldn't be any other way. Type `kindergarten.canJoin === army.canJoin` into the console. You get `true`. If you want the extraterrestrial to not shrug, you are asking for the impossible. Think about it. *it couldn't be any other way* - the information is not there.

`army.canJoin=canJoin` does not modify ('*put initials on*') the `canJoin` function, neither does `kindergarten.canJoin=canJoin` - just as putting something into a drawer does not put initials on it. In `institution.canJoin(...)` we know that `this` is `institution` - a function call takes place here. If, on the other hand, the parenthesis aren't there, no function call takes place. *the spoon is out of the drawer*.

As pointed out in other answers, you can use `bind` to 'put your initials onto the spoon'. Personally, I never use `bind`. I'm with the the camp that regards the whole `this` contraption of JS (`this` = 'the you-know-what-I-mean-object' (except if you don't)) as a weakness of the language. I prefer to construct closures, as explained below (following code will make `Array.filter` work without second argument)

```
function createAgeFilter(min,max){
    return function(item){
        return item.age>=min && item.age<max;
    };
}

army.canJoin = createAgeFilter(army.minAge, army.maxAge);
kindergarten.canJoin = createAgeFilter(kindergarten.minAge, kindergarten.maxAge);
```

With the above, so-to-speak, you're making spoons that have initials on them right from the start, rather than putting them on at a later point, with `bind`.

You can probably confirm that newbies find the above *much* easier to read, compared to anything using `bind`.

**UPDATE**

Using ES6 classes ***does not*** *change the nature of the issue*.

```js
class Army {
  constructor(t){
    this.tankCount=t;this.minAge=18;this.maxAge=27
  }
  canJoin(user){
    return user.age >= this.minAge && user.age < this.maxAge;
  }
}
class Kindergarten {
  constructor(t){
    this.toyCount=t;this.minAge=2;this.maxAge=6
  }
}
Kindergarten.prototype.canJoin = Army.prototype.canJoin;

var myArmy = new Army(5);
var myKG = new Kindergarten(5);

var cast=[{name:'Susie',age:3},{name:'Agamemnon',age:5},{name:'Salome',age:18},{name:'Herod',age:40}]

function getName(u){ return u.name; }

var e1 = document.getElementById('one');
var e2 = document.getElementById('two');
var e3 = document.getElementById('three');
var e4 = document.getElementById('four');

e1.textContent = cast.filter(Army.prototype.canJoin, myArmy).map(getName).join(',');
e2.textContent = cast.filter(Army.prototype.canJoin, myKG).map(getName).join(',');
e3.textContent = cast.filter(Kindergarten.prototype.canJoin, myArmy).map(getName).join(',');
e4.textContent = cast.filter(Kindergarten.prototype.canJoin, myKG).map(getName).join(',');
```

```html
<div id='one'></div>
<br>
<div id='two'></div>
<br>
<div id='three'></div>
<br>
<div id='four'></div>
```

```
Salome = {name:'Salome',age:18};
myArmy.canJoin(Salome);  // true
myKG.canJoin(Solame); // false
f = myArmy.canJoin;
f(Salome);             // error
```

notice that error. `f` is *still* not bound to the `Army` class! Just because you used ES6 classes, that *does not* make that error go away and *does not* (as you see) bind in the way you might have thought. And you still need 2nd argument to filter function if you use ES6 classes like this.